# AWS TO OCI GOLDENGATE REPLICATION

Tags: oracle, amazon-rds, goldengate

I want to use oracle Goldengate to my Multi cloud setup database, I'm just wondering if Im required to down my primary database to avoid data discrepancy? or goldengate can sync the data even if my primary running while im setting up the goldengate to my primary and dr database?

Answer (score 0):

Goldengate can sync the changes made during the configuration from the archivelogs. Replication can be configured without stopping the source database or suspending activity in it.